# Angular Can't access _body with custom error Message from HttpErrorResponse from .net core webapi

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to access the `_body` or `body` property of an error response, which I am handling an `HttpErrorResponse` from a WebAPI. In Visual Studio Code, I can see there is a `_body` property in the error object but I am not able to access the error string. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my component ts code:

```
  this.accountService.changePassword(this.user)
  .subscribe((data : any)=>{
         this.message = "Your password was successfully changed";
      },         
      (err : HttpErrorResponse)=>{

         this.errorMessage = err.message;
         Observable.throw(err);
     });
```

My service ts code:

return this.http.post(environment.myurl, user);

My WebAPi code is

```
   if (success) {
     return Created("", userpassword;
   } else
   {
       return BadRequest(userpassword.error);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse there's no `body` field in `HttpErrorResponse` or `HttpResponseBase` class.

Use HttpErrorResponse's message field as you are already doing.

Answer (score 0):

After checking my code over and over again, I was using HTTP instead of HttpClient